# How to change account name in macOS Ventura?

Tags: user-account, ventura

macOS Ventura has new System Preferences app and account names can no longer be changed from System Preferences > Users & Groups > *(select a user)* > Account name.

Comment: There is no obvious option to do this on macOS 12.6 (Monterey) either. At least on 12.6 you can right click on the user and hit "advanced options". It shows some entries including the name, however, there is a big warning included, so i am not sure if this is a smart idea.

Comment: @X_841 Well, this is the way documented on https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201548 (but I share your doubts about this not being a smart idea in general).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just found out that you can simply right-click on the account you want to configure, to get to *Advanced Options* menu.

All the other steps are the same with macOS Monterey and later, as [documented](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201548) on Apple website.

[image: A screenshot of Users & Groups settings]

Comment: Yes but note the **WARNING** in red just above the User ID. So I would make a full backup of that disk before proceeding, and then *also* how badly you need to do this, because Apple's warnings like that are practically non-existent.